# Sorting and Paging issues

Tags: extjs

I would like to sort the whole dataset instead of page by page sorting.But for some reason it is sorting page by page instead of the whole dataset.Could you please help me in this issue.Iam using a grouping store.

```
    var store = new FMP.AspNetJsonStore({
        fields: [
                       { name: 'AssetID' },
                       { name: 'AssociationID' },
                       { name: 'Image' },
                       { name: 'StatusName' },
                       { name: 'ModelName' },
                       { name: 'IPAddress' },
                       { name: 'InScope', type: 'boolean' },
                       { name: 'ServicePlanName' },
                       { name: 'PricePlanName' },
                       { name: 'PricePlanDescription' },
                       { name: 'Program' },
                       { name: 'ServicePlanID' },
                       { name: 'Customer' },
                       { name: 'Black', type: 'float' },
                       { name: 'Cyan', type: 'float' },
                       { name: 'Magenta', type: 'float' },
                       { name: 'Yellow', type: 'float' },
                       { name: 'BlackPct' },
                       { name: 'CyanPct' },
                       { name: 'MagentaPct' },
                       { name: 'YellowPct' },
                       { name: 'PrinterMarkerSupplies' },
                       { name: 'PageCount' },
                       { name: 'BlackImpressions' },
                       { name: 'ColorImpressions' },
                       { name: 'PricePlanID' },
                       { name: 'ResponsibilityForAction' },
                       { name: 'PrinterSerialNumber' }

                    ],

        totalProperty: "TotalCount",
        autoLoad: { params: { start: 0, limit: myPageSize} },
        //autoLoad: true,
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            // Call web service method using GET syntax
            url: 'GetPrintersGrid.asmx/buildGrid',
            // Ask for Json response
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
            method: "GET"
        }),
        //remoteSort: true,
        sortInfo: { field: 'PageCount', direction: "DESC" },
        groupField: 'Customer',
        root: 'Records'
    });
```

Here is my web service.

```
public PagedResult<FMPAsset> buildGrid(int start, int limit)
{
    Guid AccountID = (Guid)Session["AccountID"];
    string whereClause = "SELECT value a FROM XSP_AssetList_V AS a WHERE a.AccountID = GUID'" + AccountID + "'";
    List<FMPAsset> fmpAssets = new List<FMPAsset>();



    using (XSPAssetModel.XSPAssetEntities assetEntities = new XSPAssetEntities(b.BuildEntityConnectionString1("XSMDSN")))
    {
        ObjectQuery<XSP_AssetList_V> assets = new ObjectQuery<XSP_AssetList_V>(whereClause, assetEntities);
        var assetPage = assets.OrderBy(x=>x.StatusName).Skip(start).Take(limit);
        var totalAssetCount = assets.Count();


        currentAssets = assetPage.ToList();
        int currentAssetsCount = currentAssets.Count;
        string imgprefix = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImgPrefix"];
        char[] separators = { '/' };
        string appname = "";
        int lastloc = imgprefix.Substring(0, imgprefix.Length - 1).LastIndexOfAny(separators);
        if (lastloc > 6)
        {
            appname = imgprefix.Substring(lastloc + 1);
        }


        FMPAsset asset = new FMPAsset();

        //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\test.txt");

        XSPPrinterMarkerSupplyModel.XSPPrinterMarkerSupplyEntities markerCtx = new XSPPrinterMarkerSupplyModel.XSPPrinterMarkerSupplyEntities(b.BuildEntityConnectionString1("XSMDSN"));

        for (int x = 0; x < currentAssetsCount; x++)
        {
            asset = new FMPAsset();

            asset.AssetID = currentAssets[x].AssetID.ToString();
            asset.PricePlanID = currentAssets[x].PricePlanID.ToString();
            asset.AssociationID = currentAssets[x].AssociationID;
            asset.ModelName = currentAssets[x].ModelName;
            asset.ResponsibilityForAction = currentAssets[x].ResponsibilityForAction;
            asset.IPAddress = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentAssets[x].PrinterIPAddress)) ? "No IP" : currentAssets[x].PrinterIPAddress; ;

                            Guid id = currentAssets[x].AssetID;

            asset = SetCMYKvalues(asset, x);

            BuilldImpressionsValues(currentAssets[x], ref asset);
            fmpAssets.Add(asset);
        }


        var y = new PagedResult<FMPAsset>();
        y.Records =  fmpAssets;
        y.TotalCount = totalAssetCount;
        return y;




    }

}
```

I also tried sorting all the records and then returning only first 10 records but i was not able to sort the whole dataset instead it was doing page page .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*remoteSort : boolean
true if sorting is to be handled by requesting the Proxy to provide a refreshed version of the data object in sorted order, as opposed to sorting the Record cache in place (defaults to false).*

Try setting remoteSort to true.

Comment: So, it appears your problem is with the OVER clause.  I suggest extracting your SQL (you have done this already) and using the console for your database to fix the SQL (or reconfig the database).  When that is working, return the new new SQL into the backend code and try again.